# How to fix ServerSocket only executing first received command?

Tags: java, sockets

I wrote a Socket client and ServerSocket program. The client runs on PC1 and sends commands to the serversocket on the second pc. The client runs perfectly well (confirmed with print statements), but after the server reaches any of the case statement of the switch (code below), it stops. I tested with print statements and it never leaves the "case x" block. It just executes the dt.browse(...) command and then seems to stop there. Is this the browse command that is blocking or am I missing something?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(...);


    while (true) {
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        byte command = dIn.readByte();
        System.out.println("received command:"+command);
        switch (command) {
            case 1:
                try
                {
                    URI uri = new URI("https://www.google.ch/");
                    Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
                    dt.browse(uri);
                }
                catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
                //Runtime.getRuntime().exec("start /max chrome google.ch");
                break;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What are your observations on the "server C"? does a browser instance open? Does your program continue if you close the browser?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that. Yes, the first command opens the browser. The program seems to continue. at least it doesn't execute the print statement i put at the closing command `case 16:
                    System.out.println("closing");
                    socket.close();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("invalid command");
                    break;`